# SQLAlchemy: Joined Inheritance with One-to-One Relationship

Tags: python, inheritance, sqlalchemy, one-to-one

I'm trying to accomplish the following [joined inheritance](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html#joined-table-inheritance) with [one-to-one relationship](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-one) structure with SQLAlchemy: `Box` and `Item` are both `Element`s, and `Box` has an `Item`.

[image: UML relationship diagram illustrating inheritance from Box to Element and Item to Element, and aggregation of Item by Box.]

The class definitions are as follows:

```
class Element(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'element'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    el_type = Column(String)

    __mapper_args__ = dict(
        polymorphic_identity='element',
        polymorphic_on=el_type,
    )

class Box(Element):
    # Joined table inheritance: Element.
    __tablename__ = 'box'
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('element.id'), primary_key=True)
    __mapper_args__ = dict(polymorphic_identity='box')

    # One-to-one relationship: Item.
    item = relationship('Item',
        back_populates='box', uselist=False)

    def __init__(self, item_name=None):
        self.item = Item(item_name)

class Item(Element):
    # Joined table inheritance: Element.
    __tablename__ = 'item'
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('element.id'), primary_key=True)
    __mapper_args__ = dict(polymorphic_identity='item')

    # One-to-one relationship: Box.
    box_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('box.id'))
    box = relationship('Box',
        back_populates='item')

    name = Column(String)

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

When I try to instantiate `b = Box('rock')`, I get:

`sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Box.item - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.`

Now I have gone to SQLAlchemy's [page on this issue](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#handling-multiple-join-paths) (great docs, I might add), but I'm not sure how to bridge the gap between their example and my situation. I thought this might fix it:

```
class Item(Element):
    # ...
    box = relationship('Box',
        back_populates='item', foreign_keys=[id, box_id])
    # ...
```

...but I get the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

---

### UPDATE:

I have now tried using [`ForeignKeyConstraint`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#sqlalchemy.schema.ForeignKeyConstraint) constructs in an effort to more explicitly describe the desired behavior to SQLAlchemy; to no avail:

```
class Box(Element):
    # ...
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    # ...

    ForeignKeyConstraint([id], ['element.id'])

    # ...

class Item(Element):
    # ...
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    # ...

    # One-to-one relationship: Box.
    box_id = Column(Integer)
    box = relationship('Box',
        back_populates='item')

    ForeignKeyConstraint([id, box_id], ['element.id', 'box.id'])

    # ...
```

A simple `AssertionError` is thrown back at me (no description). Given that SQLAlchemy has a good track record of producing meaningful error messages, could this suggest that this is an unanticipated situation?

Comment: An explicit `ForeignKeyConstraint` should be passed in `__table_args__` instead of just constructing it in class body.

Comment: @IljaEverilä is that just convention? Having `ForeignKeyConstraint` in the class body for `Box` and `Item` works fine if `Item` inherits from `Base` instead of `Element`. (I'm using v1.3.0)

Comment: It's not, though SQLA might make the connection through use of the actual `id` column instead of passing its name as a string. It at least does that with `Index`.

Comment: Relevant docs: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#setting-up-constraints-when-using-the-declarative-orm-extension

Comment: @IljaEverilä you are correct in thinking that SQLA makes the connection through the Column instance. If I put the contents of the first list of the `Box` `ForeignKeyConstraint` in quotes, I get a `NoForeignKeysError`. Likewise for `Item`.